# Let's face it: should [facebook-account-kit] and [account-kit] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I recently reviewed an edit where the only change was to remove the [account-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account-kit) tag and replace it with [facebook-account-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-account-kit). From the descriptions, I don't see any real difference between the two. Should these tags be merged?

Comment: Which one would be the master?

Comment: @rene account-kit, I think, just based on reading the descriptions.  It also has more questions associated with it.

Comment: 13 questions ... might as well hand re-tag ... do it before 03:00 and the tag is gone ... on the other hand facebook-account-kit seems clearer so I kind of expected that to become the master ... No, I'm not helpful, I just don't know what is wise, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, they are the same and even the tag wikis were the same. I have synonymized them.

[account-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account-kit) is the master here, so from now, posts tagged with [facebook-account-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-account-kit) will get automatically mapped to [account-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account-kit)